# To air is human

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

It eats lots of salad, lives right under your noses.
"An Austrian husband?" the Fraulein supposes.
It's in a shy airport; things like to run through it.
Quit scratching your head; I know you can do it!

Comment: It sounds a kind of rot13(oevqtr)..., for example rot13(nreb-oevqtr)...!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> Hair (and its homophones)

It eats lots of salad,

> **Hares** and rabbits like eating lettuce and other greenery.

..lives right under your noses.

> A moustache is pretty hairy (and a nod to @Phylyp!)

"An Austrian husband?" the Fraulein supposes.

> An Austrian (or other German-speaking) man is a **Herr**.

It's in a shy airport;

> The word is hidden in a "s**h**y **air**port", and also one of the world's major airports is Chicago O'**Hare**

things like to run through it.

> People run their fingers through their hair. Other people and animals have insects running through theirs.

Quit scratching your head;

> You'll mess your hair up if you do

I know you can do it!

> You can "do" your hair or get a good " 'do" at the hairdresser's.

Comment: That sounds really appropriate! A bunch of rot13(ubzbalzf). Well done!

Comment: Pretty good. Can you find a *specific* "shy airport?" Maybe there's a missing apostrophe in the last line?

Comment: Likely rot13(B'Uner) for the specific airport, @IanF1

Comment: @Chowzen just spotted what you meant by the apostrophe too!

Comment: I'll bequeath a checkmark unto you, my *heir*, in a little while, If I didn't, I would be in err. :)

Comment: @Chowzen danke, mein Herr.

Answer (score 2):

I might be interpreting this waaaay too literally, but are you:

> **A MOUSTACHE**

It eats lots of salad,

> A large bushy moustache is liable to catch food

lives right under your noses.

> Yep, right on the upper lip

"An Austrian husband?" the Fraulein supposes.

> I can only think of [one infamous Austrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler) and his style of moustache

It's in a shy airport;

> The nostrils are an air port, an opening for air

things like to run through it.

> Combs are used to groom a moustache

Comment: I like the "airport" idea, but [those] are totally "in-your-face" rather than shy! :) The correct answer will find the 4th line to be more than just filler.

Comment: Aah, so that's a nice clue about the 4th line! @Chowzen